# Installed .sty with tlmgr but latex can't find it

Tags: texlive, mdframed

I have installed Tex live 2013 Version 3.1415926 and I want to install the package mdframed.

My first try was to enter in the terminal

```
tlmgr install mdframed
```

but the terminal responded to me that I am not allowed to do that.
When I entered

```
sudo tlmgr install mdframed
```

I gained the message "tlmgr: command not found". So I typed

```
sudo -i
```

added the tex path in /root/.bashrc and finally entered

```
tlmgr install mdframed
tlmgr update mdframed
```

and it worked! But if I compile my latex file the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mdframed.sty' not found.
```

remains. Any Idea how to solve it?

EDIT: Output of

```
kpsewhich mdframed.sty
```

is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty
```

Comment: Do you work under Unix? Maybe you have different paths. Did you try compiling the file from the terminal? Please show us the output in the terminal of `kpsewhich mdframed.sty`.

Comment: Yes I work under Unix. Thank you for the hint to try to compile in terminal - that did work. I use texmaker but it does not seem to work there. The command line for Pdflatex is `pdflatex   -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Comment: I just noticed that in the log file from texmaker the first line is `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)` instead of Tex Live 2013. Can you tell me how to change that?

Comment: Take a look at [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu): the bit about finalising installation covers paths.

Comment: You have multiple installations of TeX. TeXMaker is using Debian's TL. At the command line, you are getting upstream's. The link @JosephWright provided explains how to clean up and make things more coherent.